# Graph & Network Mining: clustering/community detection/ classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, graphs

I am working on graphs/networks where nodes and edges have some attributes.

I want to know what algorithm exist for:

1) **clustering a graph to *k* groups:** depend only on the structure (**edge** attribute only)

2) **Community Detection:** ( same as graph clustering) but the number of communities is unknown.

3) **Classification:** a supervised method where I have labels and I want to classify the nodes based on their attributes and their connections (edges).

4) **Page Rank:** detecting the most important nodes in a group (community, cluster) based on their connection

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... Some points. Networked data is modeled with graphs. When you have different attributes you have [Property Graph](https://markorodriguez.com/2011/02/08/property-graph-algorithms/).

For clustering, you can extract the topology of the subgraph based on desired attributes and then use any [Modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_(networks))-based algorithm (most recommended is [Blondel algorithm](https://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.blondel/research/louvain.html)). In Blondel algorithm you don't need to know the number of communities in advance.

Have a look at [Network Science book by Barabasi](http://networksciencebook.com/) to get more insight to networks.

For classification you may extract features from graphs and use common classification algorithms or use graph kernels and feed it to kernel methods such as SVM. Follow [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27074/8878).

Page rank is one of the methods for ranking but you have simpler choices according to your problem. See [Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) measures from the book above. There you can also see details of different ranking algorithms.

If you need more info you may drop a comment here.

Hope it helped. Good Luck!

Comment: Hello, I have been reading state of the art method regarding the problems I have and I have some questions to ask:

Comment: 1-for the clustering problem I have seen methods based on minimum cuts like Gomory–Hu tree but when reading some survey it doesn't figure out with the other algorithm such as spectral clustering https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1062v2.pdf
I want to know why?

Comment: 2 you said that in the clustering I need to extract some the topology of the subgraph based on attributes but in my case I only want to take the current connection in the graph as if the node don’t have attribute (for the clustering I only need to take the arcs attributes “weights” into consideration)

Comment: 3 for the classification problem I want to know how to represent the connection (arc) between the nodes as attributes. I read something about GCN (graph convolutional neural network) which take the different connection of a node into consideration. SO I want to know what are the traditional methods for taking the connection into consideration if I will not use GCN

Comment: 1) The paper you mentioned is a standard survey for Community detection. Both Andrea and Santo Fortunato are experts in this field. The reason comes from a funny fact :D This problem has been studied in 3 different fields for a long time with some overlap but not completely! In Statistical Physics (where these guys come from) you call it "Community Detection", in CS they call it "Graph Clustering" (see Ulrike Von Luxburg) and in Mathematics they call it "Graph Partitioning" (see Miroslav Fiedler). So you have 3 approaches to the same problem which do not necessarily overlap whole the time!

Comment: 2) So even simpler! When you discard the attributes on nodes and edges (except of weights) you have a weighted graph and there are tones of algorithms for clustering weighted graphs including Blondel algorithm which is originally for weighted graphs.

Comment: 3) Well ... GCN is a pretty new approach to this problem and recently gained lots of popularity. Traditionally for graph classification, either you extract features from the topology like average shortest path, clustering coefficient, number of triangles, etc. and use a traditional classifier. Or you use methods who accept structured data like kernel methods that I mentioned above. See also the work of Horst Bunke from University of Bern. He worked on this problem for a long long time. (http://www.fki.inf.unibe.ch/staff/prof.-dr.-horst-bunke)
If it helped you may consider upvote :)

Comment: I did but I don't have enough points to make it public thx by the way

Comment: You are welcome! You may consider accepting the answer if it answered your question. Contributions to this community are from dedicated personal time. Feels good to get some flowers for that ;) @MohamedAmineOuali

Comment: If I want to search about more features that I can extract form the graph topology besides average shortest path, clustering coefficient number of triangles what term should I use to search. I want to know the options that I have)

Comment: simply start from the great book by Barabasi http://networksciencebook.com/